# Allow circular references and imported modules in Typescript

Tags: typescript, import, module

I have a typescript project with circular references, ie. class A references class B and class B references class A. Furthermore, there are external modules that contain `export` statements. I can't change these.

**Approach 1**

Use import statements:

```
import { ClassName } from './path/to/the/file';
```

This doesn't allow circular references. Rewriting the code to avoid circular references is not an option for me.

**Approach 2**

Have one `definitions.d.ts` file that references every file in the project like this:

```
/// <reference path="path/to/the/file"/>
```

Then, in every code file the definitions file is referenced the same way.

This solution seems to allow circular references. However, external module files with `export` statements can't be referenced like this so I need to use `import` statements. The problem is, once a file uses an `import` statement, it seems to become a module as well and can no longer be referenced using the `/// <reference` directive.

What is a good project structure that allows circular references and external modules?

Edit: Putting both classes into the same file does exactly what I want. Is there a way to achieve the same while keeping a separate file for each class?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try to work around this by extracting an interface, although I find it quite annoying.

I guess it can be an advantage to expose only the required methods/fields to keep code-completion suggestion lists cleaner:

```
export interface C {
    ...
}
```

Class A now implements C:

```
export class A implements C {
    ...
}
```

And change class B to refer to C instead of A:

```
export class B {
    private a : C;
    // instead of private a : A;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You should avoid circular references, there are not many good options and a lot of issues. A way of doing it should be to create a Class C containing your Class A and Class B and avoid internal referencing between A and B, and implementing the mixed functionality in your Class C.

Comment: What are the issues with circular references? I want to avoid adding lots of boilerplate code.

Comment: In my case, a parent class references its subclass.

Comment: Circular solutions are not scalable, are not supported by tooling and IDES, and there exist many other composition or structural patterns (In the Gamma-Helm-Johnson and Vlissides sense) known to help avoid circular referencing. Like Composite or Facade patterns.

Comment: This doesn't really help me... I just copied both classes into the same file and it works perfectly fine, it just looks bad. Maybe the best solution is to concatenate all `*.ts` files before running `tsc`.